# Why aren't the changes made inside a spec reflected in database used by a remote app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm writing a feature test using Capybara and RSpec where the app is remote (i.e. not started by Capybara). The test and the app share the same database. So I assumed that any change the test makes to the database would be available to the remote app as well.

But when I use Selenium to fill in forms with data from the records I created in my test steps, I get "No such record" errors.

My RSpec configuration includes this line:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

I assumed this would allow the data to be available for Selenium. But that's not what is happening.

My Capybara configuration is:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.app_host = 'http://selenium:5000'
Capybara.run_server = false
```

Both the test and the app under test use the same database at `DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@db:5432/test_db`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out that DatabaseCleaner was adding the transaction block.

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```